# <RequestMap> of the XML file (shibboleth2.xml)

Tags: shibboleth

```
<RequestMap applicationId="default">
<Host name="www.example.org">
    <Path name=**"secure"** authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
</Host>
```

Hi I am new to shibboleth. In "RequestMap" there is a child tag called "path". What is that tag for and what is the value should be in path name = " "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It is the path which needs to be secured.*

Suppose path is `*` then your whole `www.example.com` is secured, i.e. you need to have valid session in shibboleth to access www.example.com.

But if the path is `secure` then just `www.example.com/secure` is secured via shibboleth, you can access any `www.example.com/xyz` path without shibboleth authorization.

You can have multiple path items as child elements.

Shibboleth is an **authorization** tool, it just authorize - prevent user to access some part of module with shibboleth authentication (idP's authentication).